# Can we move the baseLine in bar charts like we do in bipolar area chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart, baseline, lightningchart

In bipolar area chart we can shift the baseline by a few units so that we can have a comparison of the data from the baseline value. 
For eg. The base line or the start of the interval is from 0 normally.I want to have my chart starting from 40 instead of 0,Can we do the same in bar charts as well? 
In the bipolar area charts we are passing a certain extra parameter while creating the series which does the job 
`const areaBipolar = xyChart.addAreaSeries({ baseline: 40, type: AreaSeriesTypes.Bipolar })` 
but the same doesn't seem to work for `RectangleSeries`

Already tried API parameters

```
const rectangles = chart.addRectangleSeries({ baseline: 4, type: RectangleSeriesTypes.Bipolar }) 
const rectangles = chart.addRectangleSeries({ baseline: 4, type: AreaSeriesTypest.Bipolar })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [addRectangleSeries](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.2.2/classes/chartxy.html#addrectangleseries) doesn't have a `baseline` option.

To achieve what you wanted you need to change your Y or X axis coordinate for the rectangles, depending if the chart is vertical or horizontal.

Let's take the [Vertical Bars](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/edit/lcjs-example-0300-verticalBars.html) example for LightningChart JS Interactive examples as the base code to work from. This example shows how to display vertical bars. In this example the rectangles start from 0 line and have some height either up or down. To have these rectangles start from 40 or any other value, you should look for the place where the rectangle dimensions are set. In this case it's

```js
// Create rect dimensions.
const rectDimensions = {
    x: x - figureThickness,
    y: 0,
    width: figureThickness,
    height: entry.value
}
// Add rect to the series.
const rect = rectangles.add(rectDimensions)
```

If you change that `y: 0` to be what you want the baseline to be, e.g. `y: 40`, the rectangles will all start from y = 40 and go up or down based on the height of the rectangle.

See the code snippet below for working example.

```js
// Extract required parts from LightningChartJS.
const {
    lightningChart,
    AxisScrollStrategies,
    SolidFill,
    ColorRGBA,
    emptyLine,
    emptyFill,
    AutoCursorModes,
    UIOrigins,
    emptyTick
} = lcjs

const lc = lightningChart()

const months = [
    'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
    'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'
]
// Define an interface for creating vertical bars.
let barChart
{
    barChart = (options) => {
        // flat red fill style for positive bars
        const flatRedStyle = new SolidFill().setColor(ColorRGBA(242, 67, 79))
        // flat blue fill style for negative bars
        const flatBlueStyle = new SolidFill().setColor(ColorRGBA(42, 171, 240))

        let x = 0
        const figureThickness = 10
        const figureGap = figureThickness * .5
        const baseline = 40
        const bars = []

        // Create a XY-Chart and add a RectSeries to it for rendering rectangles.
        const chart = lc.ChartXY(options)
            .setTitle('Changes in electricity usage between 2017 and 2018')
            .setAutoCursorMode(AutoCursorModes.onHover)
            // Disable mouse interactions (e.g. zooming and panning) of plotting area
            .setMouseInteractions(false)

        // Bar series represented with rectangles.
        const rectangles = chart.addRectangleSeries()

        // cursor
        //#region
        // Show band using Rectangle series.
        const band = chart.addRectangleSeries()
            .setMouseInteractions(false)
            .setCursorEnabled(false).add({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0 })
            .setFillStyle(new SolidFill().setColor(ColorRGBA(255, 255, 255, 50)))
            .setStrokeStyle(emptyLine)
            .dispose()
        // Modify AutoCursor.
        chart.setAutoCursor(cursor => cursor
            .disposePointMarker()
            .disposeTickMarkerX()
            .disposeTickMarkerY()
            .setGridStrokeXStyle(emptyLine)
            .setGridStrokeYStyle(emptyLine)
            .setResultTable((table) => {
                table
                    .setOrigin(UIOrigins.CenterBottom)
            })
        )
        // Change how series parses its data-points using series method.
        rectangles.setResultTableFormatter((builder, series, figure) => {
            let counter = 0
            // Find cached entry for the figure.
            const entry = bars.find((bar, index) => {
                counter = index;
                return bar.rect == figure
            }).entry
            // Parse result table content from values of 'entry'.
            return builder
                .addRow(`Month: ${months[counter]}`)
                .addRow(`Value: ${entry.value}%`)
        })
        // Apply cursor logic using series.onHover method
        rectangles.onHover((_, point) => {
            if (point) {
                const figure = point.figure
                const dimensions = figure.getDimensionsPositionAndSize()
                // Show band.
                band
                    .setDimensions({
                        x: dimensions.x - figureGap * .5,
                        y: figure.scale.y.getInnerStart(),
                        width: dimensions.width + figureGap,
                        height: figure.scale.y.getInnerInterval()
                    })
                    .restore()
            } else
                band.dispose()
        })
        //#endregion

        // X-axis of the series
        const axisX = chart.getDefaultAxisX()
            .setTitle('Quarter')
            .setMouseInteractions(false)
            .setScrollStrategy(undefined)
            // Disable default ticks.
            .setTickStyle(emptyTick)

        // Y-axis of the series
        const axisY = chart.getDefaultAxisY()
            .setTitle('(%)')
            .setMouseInteractions(false)
            .setScrollStrategy(AxisScrollStrategies.fitting)

        /**
         * Add multiple bars.
         * @param entries Add multiple bars data.
         */
        const addValues = (entries) => {
            for (const entry of entries) {
                bars.push(add(entry))
            }
        }
        /**
         * Add single bar.
         * @param entry Add a single bar data.
         */
        const addValue = (entry) => {
            bars.push(add(entry))
        }
        /**
         * Construct bar to draw.
         * @param entry Single bar data.
         */
        const add = (entry) => {
            // Create rect dimensions.
            const rectDimensions = {
                x: x - figureThickness,
                y: baseline,
                width: figureThickness,
                height: entry.value
            }
            // Add rect to the series.
            const rect = rectangles.add(rectDimensions)
            // Set individual color for the bar.
            rect.setFillStyle(entry.value > 0 ? flatRedStyle : flatBlueStyle)

            // Set view manually.
            axisX.setInterval(
                -(figureThickness + figureGap),
                x + figureGap
            )

            // Add custom tick, more like categorical axis.
            axisX.addCustomTick()
                .setValue(x - figureGap)
                .setGridStrokeLength(0)
                .setTextFormatter(_ => entry.category)
                .setMarker(marker => marker
                    .setPadding(4)
                    .setBackground((background) => background
                        .setFillStyle(emptyFill)
                        .setStrokeStyle(emptyLine)
                    )
                )
            x += figureThickness + figureGap
            // Return data-structure with both original 'entry' and the rectangle figure that represents it.
            return {
                entry,
                rect
            }
        }

        // Return public methods of a bar chart interface.
        return {
            addValue,
            addValues
        }
    }
}

// Use bar chart interface to construct series.
const chart = barChart()
// Add multiple bars at once.
chart.addValues([
    { category: '', value: 20 },
    { category: 'Q1', value: 20 },
    { category: '', value: -25 },
    { category: '', value: 40 },
    { category: 'Q2', value: 28 },
    { category: '', value: -23 },
    { category: '', value: -40 },
    { category: 'Q3', value: 35 },
    { category: '', value: 17 },
    { category: '', value: 24 },
    { category: 'Q4', value: -29 },
    { category: '', value: 15 }
])
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@1.2.2/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
<div style="height: 100%;" id="target"></div>
```